# How to locate Web elements (developed using div tags) using Selenium WebDriver if xpath fails

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the count of all mails in Gmail and the ">" button to go to older emails can't be located using Selenium, WebDriver. As it was developed using div tags, I could only use Xpath but no luck. Any help please?
the snippet of my code is below:

```
int allmails = 0;
int mails = 0;
do
    {

        WebElement table = obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/table/tbody"));

        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        mails = rows.size();

        allmails = allmails + mails;

if (obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div[3]")).getAttribute("aria-disabled").equals(""))
        {
            System.out.println("Total Emails", +allmails);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            obj.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/div[3]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }

    }while(2>1);
    obj.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: you want to locate `>` for older emails using `xpath`?

Comment: The `while(2>1)` condition is a pretty bad idea. Given the long absolute xpath in your `if`condition this will most likely end up in an endless loop, if the page code is changed. Even the insertion of some invisible HTML element might lead to that.

Comment: first of all never use absolute XPATHs, try using relative XPATHs

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. the exceptions are resolved using the if with try-catch.i agree, absolute xpaths should be avoided. Thanks again!